# Problem fetching data in react: response.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, json, api, axios, array.prototype.map

i have this component in react

```
export default function CambiosEnArchivo() {
  const [response ,setResponse]= useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url + "/datosarchivotexto")
      .then((data) => {
        setResponse(data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      },[]);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Valor1</th>
                <th>Valor2</th>
                <th>Valor3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {response.map((dato) => {
                 return <tr><td>{dato.Nombre}</td><td>{dato.Valor1}</td><td>{dato.Valor2}</td><td>{dato.Valor3}</td></tr>
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to fetch data from an api an render it in a table

Page is not rendering as this error follows up:
[image]

the api is returning this

[image]

Comment: `.then((data) => ` should probably be `.then(({data}) => `. See axios docs for how to use this library. You must make sure that you don't set `response` state variable to something that is not an Array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React .map() is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989716/react-map-is-not-a-function-error)

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url + "/datosarchivotexto")
      .then((res) => {
        setResponse(res.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      },[]);
```